# How to place JSON results from a loop into a ruby form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, loops, form-for

I'm newish to Ruby. 
Saying I'm looping through some JSON data:

```
@json["results"]["businesses"].each do |business_name|
```

and I'm specifically pulling these results out of an API

```
<%= (business_name["business"]["name"] || "").gsub(/[%!?.,;&*"]/, '') %>
```

and I want to save the data represented by that line of code into my database as the an attribute of my model business. Specifically, my model business has an attribute called business_name (coincidentally to the name in the API I'm accessing).

How would I place:

```
<%= (business_name["business"]["name"] || "").gsub(/[%!?.,;&*"]/, '') %>
```

in this form's :business_name attribute:

```
          <%= form_for :business do |f| %> 
          <%= f.input :business_name %>
          <%= f.submit class: 'btn-save btn btn-yellow' %>
          <% end %>
```

So, that when I press the button, I can automatically save

```
<%= (business_name["business"]["name"] || "").gsub(/[%!?.,;&*"]/, '') %>
```

as the attribute value of :business_name in my database with the touch of a button.

As a follow-up, did my post title make sense? I'm struggling with how to correctly ask for this.

Comment: i don't understand what exactly you want to do. is that data already in the db? or du you want to prefil the form value?

Comment: Hi phoet. I want to pre-fill the form value.

Comment: And where does the JSON come from?

Comment: The JSON is coming from some company's API. Basically, I'm spilling it out onto a page, but I wanted to give the user the option to save a particular entry (business_name) into the database with the push of a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an initial value on your input:

```
<%= f.input :business_name, value: (business_name["business"]["name"] || "").gsub(/[%!?.,;&*"]/, '') %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field#324-Force-initial-value

Comment: I tried, it, but it is throwing me an undefined method on input.